# Не работает проверка на отсутствие свойства объекта, почему?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Пишу приложение на Windows на HTML/JS на билиотеке WinJS на Visual Studio 2015.

Не работает проверка на отсутствие свойства объекта:

```js
var schedule = {
  rasp: {
    ВТОРНИК: "Я есть!"
  }
}
if (schedule.rasp.ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК) {
  console.log("объект есть");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/js/ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/js/base.js"></script>
```

Попробуйте без WinJS: проверка работает адекватно и никаких ошибок, вызывающих краш приложения, не происходит:

```js
var schedule = {
  rasp: {
    ВТОРНИК: "Я есть!"
  }
}
if (schedule.rasp.ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК) {
  console.log("объект есть");
}
```

Пробовал вот так, но ошибки всё равно лезут:

```js
var schedule = {
  rasp: {
    ВТОРНИК: "Я есть!"
  }
}
if (typeof(schedule.rasp.ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК) != undefined && schedule.rasp.ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК) {
  console.log("объект есть");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/css/ui-light.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/js/ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/js/base.js"></script>
```

Что делать и как фиксить?

Comment: Я исправил в сниппетах позицию `base.js` и `ui.js` (скрипт ошибку писал из-за этого) Явно же в этом ошибка, сначала надо линковать основной скрипт, потом дополнительный. Может, в этом у вас проблема?

Comment: Сделал откат правки.

Comment: @Crantisz ошибка не в этом. См. [скриншот](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AjKPhFr4NBmvv-FOPNUXbBHIS4h7kw). Браузеры обрабатывают условие нормально, а интерпретатор Visual Studio (движок Chakra) ругается.

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже не на ошибку, а на предупреждение.

> Скоро обработает исключение

и ниже

> Если есть обработчик, то все будет работать.

Снимите чекбокс в сообщении и будет Вам счастье

Comment: Один чёрт, библиотека выкидывает исключение, даже если я продолжаю выполнение кода и даже если я допишу `else  {}` к условию. Просто дальше выскакивает ещё одно окно: `Необработанное исключение в строке 4, столбце 318 в eval code.

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'ПОНЕДЕЛЬНИК' of undefined or null reference`. Самое главное - в браузерах код выполняется нормально, а в приложении как будто обязательно надо присутствовать свойству, и никак иначе.

Comment: `try...catch` тоже не помогает

Comment: @Kenya-West А если свойство написать латиницей?

Comment: По идее никак, сервер выдаёт кириллицу... Ладно, придётся помучиться и заменить свойства на латиницу. О результатах на днях напишу.

Comment: @Kenya-West просто проверьте. Может, предположение неверноее